# Install Windows web deploy on server core

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, iis-8

How can I install Web deploy for IIS on a server core version of Windows server. All examples Iv seen involve downloading a tool from Microsoft but Server core has a minimal GUI. Is there anyway to install this through powershell?

Comment: Server 2012 R2 allows you to install the GUI and then uninstall it. Try installing the GUI, install Web Deploy and then remove the GUI Feature for Servers and Features

Comment: Before everyone votes to migrate this to Serverfault.  You should be aware that Serverfault requires the author, to be in a business setting, and have a  good understanding of what they are doing.  [How to deal with the numerous off-topic (business environment) Windows Server questions](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11647/how-to-deal-with-the-numerous-off-topic-business-environment-windows-server-qu)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and you've probably solved it but nevertheless:

- Download the web deploy msi from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717
- put it in a path that your server core server can access
- connect via Remote Desktop to the servers console (if it's a VM, connect through e.g the Hyper-V Manager)
- `cd` to the folder where the downloaded WebDeploy msi is located (in my case `C:\install`)
- run this command `gci WebDeploy*.msi | % { msiexec /i $_.FullName }`
- now you'll get a small GUI for the installation, click through it.

now the installation has finished.

if you now can do `Add-PSSnapin WDeploySnapin3.0` without errors, then WebDeploy is installed.

This was tested on a Windows Server 2019.